# Error converting a string to int in pymysql

Tags: pymysql

I am trying to convert a string input into an integer so I can use it in a sql query and I get this exact error 
ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''")

My code is:

```
def findSimilarArticles(articleId,n):
    con=connection()
    cur=con.cursor()
    num1=int(articleId)
    sql_query='''SELECT articles.id, articles.summary 
                 from articles 
                 where articles.id=%s'''
    cur.execute(sql_query,(num1))
    results=cur.fetchall()
    return(results)
```

Comment: What is the value of `articleId`? And if you hard code the value `num1=int(20)` does it work?

Comment: the value of articleId in the database is an integer.I ran it and it worked with num1=int(20).I have run the code without the num1=int(articleId) and I had other error problems

Comment: We found the error.Our professor had fucked up a file in our project.The code was right.Thnaks for the help though